# How to show mathematically max of uniform is a sufficient statistic?

Tags: statistics

So I get that $X_i \sim Uniform(0, \theta)$ then $T = max\{X_1,..., X_N\}$ is intuitively aa sufficient statistic.

But how do I prove it mathematically?

Specifically, I learned that if $f(x^n;\theta)$ denotes the joint pdf of a sample $X^n$, then we can factorise it like so:

$$f(x^n;\theta) = g(T(x^n);\theta)h(x^n)$$

Where $g$ is a function of $\theta$ and $T$ and $h$ is not dependant on $\theta$ at all.

Most explanations to prove the max is a sufficient statistic go along these lines:

$$f(x^n;\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta^n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} I_{(0,\theta)} (x_i)$$
$$ f(x^n;\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta^n} I_{(0, \theta)}(t)$$

It seems to me that $g$ here refers to $\frac{1}{\theta^n}I_{(0,\theta)}(t)$, but what does $h$ refer to?

Comment: You can always take $h=1$. At worst, your calculation is slightly messier due to the extra factors involving functions of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with a similar issue when I was studying sufficient statistics, in context of showing that the sample mean and variance are sufficient statistics for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ in the case of IID random variables with Normal $(\mu, \sigma^2)$ distributions, where both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown.

It turns out that a useful "trick" in this area of mathematics is to define $h(x^n) = 1$. And so you can use the Fisher-Neyman factorisation theorem to show that the the statistic $T(X^n) = \text{max}\{X_1 , ... , X_n\}$ is sufficient.

Comment: I suspected such a thing, but wasn't sure. Thanks for confirming what I had thought!